# digitalocean 502 bad Gateway error nginx/1.10.3(ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

This is the first time I am using digital ocean or the first attempt to deploy my django project. I have created a droplet using 1 click install django app. I have used putty and winscp to try put my files into the droplet. After uploading files and updating settings.py and urls.py I tried to open it on the browser with the droplet ip address. I get this 502 Bad Gateway error. I couldn't find a solution for this. Please help me from here. Thank you.

```
502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3(Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Please attach config files for nginx, django and gunicorn.

Comment: 502 means server is not running.

Comment: Fixed it! Some problem with static and media path. After I have set STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT everything looks fine. Thank you